# What will happen if *.exe.config is deleted?

Tags: c#, settings, config

I added application settings to the project. These settings are saved in 'NameOfMyApp.exe.config'. What would happen if somebody were to delete this file? Is it necessary to create it again? Where should I store the values of default settings?

Comment: That same thing that happens when somebody deletes the .exe file.  It stops working properly.

Comment: But if you delete *.exe.config file programm wil be work correctly.

Comment: Well, then don't hesitate to delete it now.  Don't deploy files you don't need.

Comment: But if user chenge value in .config file. Programm will be use new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the settings designer and the generated code (in the Properties namespace) you have defaults in the (generated) code.

Answer (score 2):

If someone deletes the .config file, it's gone, baby, gone.  And it will be necessary to create, deploy, or GET it again.

Storing values of default settings - probably two obvious answers would be in a config file or a database table.  If you default settings are fairly static and not really user specific, a config file may be a good option (or are set at the initial deployment/installation).  If these values can change by the user, it's probably better to store them in the database.

I think the answer to where to store your default settings really depends on the nature of the application and how the user's use it.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE: oh, and if they do delete the config, I hope you have it stored in source control somewhere.  :)  Probably make your life a lot easier.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Program will be work correctly if there is  global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute in generated code.

I wrote simple example (Windows Forms):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace AppSettings {
        public partial class Form1 : Form {
            public Form1() {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.tbText;
            }
        }
    }
```

TbText scope is application. I compiled it in release mode. I deleted all files except *.exe. It is work correct because this setting is into assembly:

```
namespace AppSettings.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
         //here!
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("!!!***HALLO***!!!")]
         //
        public string tbText {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["tbText"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```